# Doesn’t John 9:34 lay the groundwork for what the Jewish people believed about Original Sin?

Tags: sin, original-sin

For context, we read:

> “They said to the blind man again, “What do you say about Him because
> He opened your eyes?” He said, “He is a prophet.”
>
> But the Jews did not believe concerning him, that he had been blind
> and received his sight, until they called the parents of him who had
> received his sight.
>
> And they asked them, saying, “Is this your son, who you say was born
> blind? How then does he now see?”
>
> His parents answered them and said, “We know that this is our son, and
> that he was born blind; but by what means he now sees we do not know,
> or who opened his eyes we do not know. He is of age; ask him. He will
> speak for himself.”
>
> His parents said these things because they feared the Jews, for the
> Jews had agreed already that if anyone confessed that He was Christ,
> he would be put out of the synagogue. Therefore his parents said, “He
> is of age; ask him.”
>
> So they again called the man who was blind, and said to him, “Give God
> the glory! We know that this Man is a sinner.”
>
> He answered and said, “Whether He is a sinner or not I do not know.
> One thing I know: that though I was blind, now I see.”
>
> Then they said to him again, “What did He do to you? How did He open
> your eyes?” He answered them, “I told you already, and you did not
> listen. Why do you want to hear it again? Do you also want to become
> His disciples?”
>
> Then they reviled him and said, “You are His disciple, but we are
> Moses’ disciples. We know that God spoke to Moses; as for this fellow,
> we do not know where He is from.”
>
> The man answered and said to them, “Why, this is a marvelous thing,
> that you do not know where He is from; yet He has opened my eyes!
>
> Now we know that God does not hear sinners; but if anyone is a
> worshiper of God and does His will, He hears him.
>
> Since the world began it has been unheard of that anyone opened the
> eyes of one who was born blind. If this Man were not from God, He
> could do nothing.”
>
> They answered and said to him, “**You were completely born in sins**,
> and are you teaching us?” And they cast him out.” ‭‭John‬ ‭9:17-34

‬**Q**: Besides **John 9:34**, is there any other Jewish quotations from ancient Jewish teachings outside the Bible on their view of being “**born in sins**”?

Comment: _Behold, I was shapen in iniquity, and in sin did my mother conceive me._ Psalm 51:5. _What is man, that he should be clean? and he which is born of a woman, that he should be righteous?_ Job 15:14. _Then the Lord saw that the wickedness of man was great on the earth, and that every intent of the thoughts of his heart was only evil continually._ Genesis 6:5,

Comment: @NigelJ I appreciate the feedback Nigel, I knew of all of those verses except for Job 15:14 by memory.  I am more speaking of Ancient Jewish teachings outside scripture, pardon me for that mistake.

Comment: This Q might get an answer from the Mi Yodea site on Stack - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/   Why  not try posting it there?  Doesn't seem as if anyone here knows of extra-biblical Hebraic sources. Pity, because it's a good question.